# Why Does My Webpack React Build Make So Many Chunks?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, webpack

I use the boilerplate webpack react app below. In production I get many small "chunks" from the build process. The first load of my page downloads 24mb in "chunks" and it's a somewhat simple website. After the first load a service worker serves all those assets from cache. It has our whole development team stumped, and we don't even know where to begin. Perhaps we rethink our build process?

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js

Comment: There isn't much we can tell from this. You should analyse the bundles with tools such as [Webpack Bundle Analyzer](https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer) and [Bundle Buddy](https://github.com/samccone/bundle-buddy) to see what's causing it.

Comment: A good place to start would be with "webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin".  Essentially, webpack is calling a class that breaks out common code into a separate "chunks" file.  Then, it loads everything asynchronously.  More information about CommonsChunk: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/

(EDIT: Normal webpack behavior is to bundle everything within the depedency graph into a single file.  This plugin changes that.)